# Is it possible to manipulate the polarization of unpolarized light within a medium via Electric field?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, visible-light, photons, polarization

[image: setup]

You see this setup above. There is an unpolarized light source travelling through a transparent dielectric medium. Think of this triangular shaped medium as a capacitor. there are 3 conductive sides enclosing the dielectric transparent medium.

the umpolarized light waves will travel through the medium and nothing will change unless I apply changing electric field and create zeeman effect within the volume.

Please inspect the setup below.

[image: setup and the electric field]

My question is, if I apply the wave forms like above to the conductive plates of the medium (the time it takes is less than the travelling time of the light through the medium) would it change all the photons EM orientation and make them closer to 45° as above?

It makes sense in my mind but some part of me says it shouldn't be this simple.

Comment: Some of what you said can be fixed, and then can apply under certain conditions. But may I ask why do you need this? Why not stick a polarizer either fixed or tuneable (i.e. based on liquid crystals)? On the other hand, if you are interested in theory rather than applications, why make your example so complicated? Simply consider propagation of light in some non-linear medium with additional applied electric field. In this case check Pockels and Kerr effects.

Comment: @Cryo Thank you for the comment. A pockels effect might be a good application for polarized incoming lights how ever, what I want is to route unpolarized light to a certain orientation. I do not want to use polarizer because a polarizer absorbs more than half of the light. This way might be more efficient. Just brainstorming here. Do you see any faults in the idea? If so please let me know. Or if you see any improvement.

Comment: You are missing what unpolarized light is, IMHO. Unpolarized light is light of definite polarization, which changes in a random fashion at time-scale significantly faster than your experimental setup can resolve. So to say that your polarization correction equipment will be fast enough to correct for changing polarization of the incoming light, is to say that your light is not unpolarized. But this is just semantics. Now, regarding a more phyiscal question...

Comment: Why not split your light into two beams with polarization beam splitter. The rotate both of them to be of the same polarization, and then recombine the beam?

Comment: If your polarization change is slow enough for electronics to follow you could try to correct it in the way that you suggested it. But, in reality, the polarization change will probably be way too fast, and you will waste much more energy trying to correct for polarization change on the fly. Also, what is the secenario where you would want to be so efficient? Solar batteries? Better make them polarization insensitive. Communications? Polarization there is tightly controlled (i.e. light is not unpolarized).

Comment: @Cryo Thank you for your valueable comments. I was thinking of such system for LCD (Liquid Crystal Display) backlight enhancement and improving the efficiency. In LCD's two perpendicular polarizer sheets are used. Therefore, more than 50% of the backlight is being consumed in the backend polarizer sheet. I thought maybe if we can shift the orientation of  huge part of (unpolarized) backlight in the diffuser matched to the first polarizer sheet, we would gain most of the light loss, hence the efficiency. Backlight is the most power consuming part in a television.

Comment: Not sure this is a problem that needs solving. A better way to go is to create light in a polarized state. I am also guessing they (manufacturers) have throught about it and concluded solving this problem was not worth the cost. How fast does the polarization of the backlight change? Maybe it is too fast for electronics. And anyway, we have OLED screens now. In summary, I think the general idea could work, this is not too dissimilar to LCD noise eater (but that one works to keep the amplitude stable), but IMHO there is no real need for solving it due to availability of OLED screens.